# Store gem configuration in the gem's module

Tags: ruby, rubygems

My gem exposes a module that can be included on Mongoid mapper classes to keep track of changes.

I want the user to be able to flag specific fields on their classes so that they will be handled differrently.

My idea is to create an `appendable` flag. Please see an outline of the relevant sections of the module below:

```
module PendingChanges
    included do

        attr_accessor :__appendable_fields

        private def self.appendable(field)
           self.__appendable_fields << field
        end
    end
end
```

So when the user want to flag a field on his document as "appendable" they would do something like:

```
class Person
   include PendingChanges
   field :name, type: String
   field :emails, type: Array
   appendable :emails <- this is what they would do
end
```

I don't seem to be able to make it work, as `__appendable_fields` is always `nil`. Also, I'm not confident this is the "Ruby way" of approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had to use `mattr_accessor` instead.

I'm able to access it then with `self.__appendable_fields` on the `appendable` method.